# After switching to SwiftUI App, the dynamic link does not work when the app is in the background

Tags: swift, swiftui

I recently raised the minimum deployments to 14.
Therefore, we migrated our app to comply with the App protocol.

I wrote it like the code below
Running a Firebase dynamic link when the app is in the background does not perform any logic.

Has anyone solved this problem?

App.swift

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self)
    var appDelegate
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            SplashView()
                .onOpenURL { url in
                    print("onOpenURL")
                }.onContinueUserActivity("name") { activity in
                    print("name \(activity.description)")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

SceneDelegate.swift

```
class SceneDelegate: NSObject, UIWindowSceneDelegate, ObservableObject { 

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
        ~~
    }
    
    func scene(
        _ scene: UIScene,
        willConnectTo session: UISceneSession,
        options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions
    ) {
        ~~
    }

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity) {
        ~~
    }
}
```

AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
                     restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    ~~
}

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey: Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    ~~       
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?,annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    ~~
}
```

I recently raised the minimum deployments to 14.
Therefore, we migrated our app to comply with the App protocol.

I wrote it like the code below
Running a Firebase dynamic link when the app is in the background does not perform any logic.

Has anyone solved this problem?

App.swift

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self)
    var appDelegate
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            SplashView()
                .onOpenURL { url in
                    print("onOpenURL")
                }.onContinueUserActivity("name") { activity in
                    print("name \(activity.description)")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

SceneDelegate.swift

```
class SceneDelegate: NSObject, UIWindowSceneDelegate, ObservableObject { 

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
        ~~
    }
    
    func scene(
        _ scene: UIScene,
        willConnectTo session: UISceneSession,
        options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions
    ) {
        ~~
    }

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity) {
        ~~
    }
}
```

AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
                     restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    ~~
}

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey: Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    ~~       
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?,annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    ~~
}
```